# Communication between parallel batch files

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file, 'buildAll.bat', that builds a set of projects. It will be called by another batch file, 'manager.bat'. The 'buildAll.bat' job executes in another window and outputs a lot of text. 
I want the progress of the build job to be displayed in the original window('manager.bat'), like this:

Building project 1...done.
Building project 2...done.
Building project 3...done.
...
Build completed.

How can the build progress be communicated between the two jobs ?

Comment: You might consider upgrading from CMD.EXE to PowerShell. This sort of thing becomes much easier if you're using a scripting environment created this Century.

Comment: @John: I don't see it to be much easier with PowerShell, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary files, for example.

**buildAll.cmd**

```
del /Q %TEMP%\Project*Done>nul 2>&1
...
rem build project 1
copy nul %TEMP%\Project1Done >nul
rem build project 2
copy nul %TEMP%\Project2Done >nul
...
```

**manager.cmd**

```
...
<nul set /p X=Building project 1 ... 
:waitforproject1
if exists %TEMP%\Project1Done goto project1done
ping -n 1 localhost >nul 2>&1
goto waitforproject1
:project1done
echo done.

<nul set /p X=Building project 2 ... 
:waitforproject2
if exists %TEMP%\Project2Done goto project2done
ping -n 1 localhost >nul 2>&1
goto waitforproject2
:project2done
echo done.
...
```

Of course, this can be made much more powerful by relaying information about what projects are built and so on to the manager. But in principle it's easily possible.